# How to change and render variable in one function?

Tags: swiftui

Hi my goal is to render the view everytime a state change. However, when I call the function, it only render after the last `onSubmitStatus = .success`:

Expected print result:

```
initial
loading
success
```

Actual print result:

```
initial
success
```

Is there a way to fix this?

```
enum OnSubmitStatus {
    case initial
    case loading
    case success
    case failure
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var onSubmitStatus: OnSubmitStatus = .initial
    
    func onSubmit() {
        onSubmitStatus = .loading
        
        onSubmitStatus = .success
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            switch onSubmitStatus {
            case .initial:
                Button {
                    onSubmit()
                } label: {
                    Text("Submit")
                }
                .onAppear {
                    print("initial")
                }
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
                    .onAppear {
                        print("loading")
                    }
            case .success:
                Text("Success")
                    .onAppear {
                        print("Success")
                    }
            case .failure:
                Text("Failure")
                    .onAppear {
                        print("Failure")
                    }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

PS: using `withAnimation(body:,completion:)` works but it's ugly. Is there a way to make it more natural?

```
    func onSubmit() {
        withAnimation {
            onSubmitStatus = .loading
        } completion: {
            onSubmitStatus = .success
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are probably freezing the main thread/actor somehow. Make sure you are using concurrency so you can move stuff off the main thread/actor

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is impossible by design. SwiftUI coalesces all State changes together, and then re-evaluates the View hierarchy. This is at the heart of how SwiftUI works. You need to reconsider what you're trying to achieve with this and go another way.

Animating the way you are is possibly reasonable, but doesn't quite seem to be what you're really trying to achieve. I expect what you want is more like this:

```
func onSubmit() async {
    onSubmitStatus = .loading
    // Do whatever async work you need here. Or we can simulate work with Thread.sleep.
    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
    onSubmitStatus = .success
}
```

You then would need to slightly modify the call:

```
        case .initial:
            Button {
                Task { await onSubmit() }
            } ...
```

(The above is sloppy and can run the risk of double-tapping the Button. It is here mostly to show the general approach with minimal extra code. For a more robust solution, see [Building an asynchronous SwiftUI button](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/building-an-async-swiftui-button/).)

Comment: `SwiftUI coalesces all State changes together, and then re-evaluates the View hierarchy.` noted. How about this BLoC? https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/swift-bloc-example

Comment: I don't know what a BLoC is. Which part of this link are you asking about?

Comment: This is the BLoC (inspired by Flutter). https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/swift-bloc-example/tree/main/EmitExample/Core/BLoC. Anyway, I just tested BLoC, it does not work well with `.sheet(isPresented:)`. I will shelf this pattern and use `@Published`, it is simpler.